# Make a property mandatory based on another property of the same object in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, types, conditional-types

I have an use case

```
  interface MakeMandatory {
    name: string;
    age?: number; //
    isHiringPossible?: boolean
  }
```

Here, age and isHiringPossible is optional but if age contains value then isHiringPossible should also contain value and vice versa. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You actually have two types. One where `age` and `isHiringPossible` are both missing, and one where both are required. And what you want is a type that is the union of those two types.

```
interface MakeMandatoryMinimal {
    name: string;
    age?: undefined;
    isHiringPossible?: undefined
}

interface MakeMandatoryComplete {
    name: string;
    age: number;
    isHiringPossible: boolean
}

type MakeMandatory = MakeMandatoryMinimal | MakeMandatoryComplete
```

Now you can test `age` which will prove that `isHiringPossible` exists, like so:

```
declare const data: MakeMandatory // pretend we have object of type MakeMandatory

data.isHiringPossible // type: boolean | undefined

if (data.age) {
    data.isHiringPossible // type: boolean
}
```

[See Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?strictPropertyInitialization=false#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgLJwNYXSAJnMAeygE9VRgBbOAG2QG8AoZF5EOSiALmQGcwooAOYBuZqzhCIAfh4BXPBBigIuMa2TBeACWCCQQgAqFevYACMaM+YuUhVjAL6NGoSLEQp0WHPiKkAYUJKAAcrSAZxFnZOHn59USjkSW42OUpzaHVWLV0E41MLKx5zQkIrOBAnFzASEK9MbEq-YhJkAF40Rt8CVvIQKlpkAB8un2bewOCwiEgXXAgEGjgoFARCEH5kPzgebya8SZIXRh2AOly9YQKzSxQAenvkWvqSsoqQEeQFBbsHVxgyAAFOcUgBKSIac6XfImW5WZCPZ51VKlcoQSrVRhAA)